# Is there a way I can update a dockerfile with variables from the Azure Pipeline?

Tags: bash, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline that I am trying to build. Inside the dockerfile there needs to be variables for some sensitive information regarding our Azure Keyvault, my goal is to not have this information stored in any file, rather have the pipeline update the dockerfile on run; I have create a simple bash script inside the repo that the pipeline is set to run, it will take the variable names and update the dockerfile, however it says it cannot find the docker file..

This is the script,

```
sed -i "s/<AZURE_CLIENT_ID>/${1}/g" Dockerfile

sed -i "s/<AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET>/${2}/g" Dockerfile

sed -i "s/<AZURE_TENANT_ID>/${3}/g" Dockerfile

sed -i "s/<KEY_VAULT_NAME>/${4}/g" Dockerfile
```

I have set the arguments in the Pipeline, and used an echo command to ensure they're returning the desired values.

This is the error I get:

***sed: can't read Dockerfile: No such file or directory
/home/vsts/work/1/s/update-docker-var.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found***

I have tried using the 'ls' command and the 'pwd' command but they both return nothing... I am kind of stumped here, any help would be great. Thank you!

This is the bash section of the pipeline YAML:

```
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      filePath: 'update-docker-var.sh'
      arguments: '$(AZURE_CLIENT_ID) $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET) $(AZURE_TENANT_ID) $(KEY_VAULT_NAME)'
      workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

Comment: You shell script has dos line endings.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for your response! This is a bash script, but I do notice the "$'\r': command not found" in the returned error. I have updated my original post to include the pipeline YAML, I don't know why it is using dos line endings...

Comment: Edit the `update-docker-var.sh` file and remove dos line endings.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you so much that worked! If you want to put it in an answer so i can mark it as correct.

Comment: This isn't secure embedding secrets in this manner. [Here is an brief intro on how to do it.](https://medium.com/@mccode/dont-embed-configuration-or-secrets-in-docker-images-7b2e0f916fdd). If you need them available at run time, then you should have `ENV` declared in your `Dockerfile` and then pass in the secrets in a secure manner (read the article for some tips). If you need them available at build time then declare `ARG` in your `Dockerfile` and pass them in via `--build-arg` ([link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg))